# php I need every line uniq by generate_string and preg_replace

Tags: php

I want to replace every line by php code using preg_replace but its not giving me uniq every line. I need every line uniq

```
<?php      
$permitted_chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

function generate_string($input, $strength = 16) {
    $input_length = strlen($input);
    $random_string = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < $strength; $i++) {
        $random_character = $input[mt_rand(0, $input_length - 1)];
        $random_string .= $random_character;
    }

    return $random_string;
}

$new= generate_string($permitted_chars, 30);
$old='/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+/m';

$data = file_get_contents("txt.txt");
$newdata = preg_replace($old, $new, $data);

file_put_contents("txt.txt", $newdata);
?>
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created only one random unique id with your call at

```
$new= generate_string($permitted_chars, 30);
```

This value `$new` will now be used in any replacements you are doing. So it is obviously the same for every line.

You have to call `generateString()` for every line individually. You can use `preg_replace_callback()` and provide a function which generates a new value for each line you have.

```
// example data
$data = "1|http://www.example.org
5|http://www.example.org/again
30|http://www.example.org/another_one";

$old = '/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+/m';
$newdata = preg_replace_callback(
    $old, // the regex
    function($matches) use ($permitted_chars) { // the magic anonymous function
        return generate_string($permitted_chars, 30);
    },
    $data); // the original data
echo $newdata;
```

This might generate an output like the follow:

```
5ZcOpJIXO7Q0YNQWRlTxc16LZSlrqy|http://www.example.org
JeoGTQz6HYSZcF3iUrm2YS66AXXDH0|http://www.example.org/again
Wp4UIdv24IK6SxuUr9m9R2TuO4Cjzb|http://www.example.org/another_one
```

Comment: Thanks Man its perfect answer and exactly what I wanted